# Is there an equivalent of Source Outliner for Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I'm just learning Java, so this may be obvious.
I'm wondering is there an equivalent of Source Code Outliner for Java in Eclipse?
Or where is it located in the IDE?

Second, How do I navigate to the declaration statement of an object/variable via keyboard shortcut similiar to Visual Studio right click>"go to definition"?

Comment: What is "Source Code Outliner"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to definition:

1. hit F3
2. right click and choose go to definition

Outline:

1. there is quick outline for the current source file: hit ctrl+O
2. Or a separate window (default visible I thought?) Else show it by on
   the menu selecting Window->Show View->Outline
3. Expand the source file in the package explorer window to the left. (click the symbol
   just to the left of the file name)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by Source Outliner you mean http://sourcecodeoutliner.codeplex.com/ then the equivalent view in Eclipse is

**Window → Show View → Outline** or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>

...but this should be visible by default down the right-hand side if you're in the Java perspective.

There is also a quick popup outline that can be accessed from the editor using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

To go to the declaration of a variable, or definition of a method, just position the text cursor over it and press <kbd>F3</kbd>. The mouse shortcut for this is to Control-click on an element in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Shift + Q for the outline view.

The answer to your second question, press ctrl when moused over the method and it will say "Open Declaration" and "Open Implementation". Another short cut is to press F3 and it will take you to the declaration or the method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the Outline View, there is also a quick outline popup that can be called in most editors using Ctrl-O shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

For Outline:

- Popup Style: In a Java file, press `Ctrl + O` (Press `Ctrl + O` again to show inherited members).
- View Style: Menu `Window` > `Show View` > `Outline`

For navigate to declaration statement:

- `Ctrl + Click` (in element); or
- With cursor in element, press `F3`.